# Traversing through a binary tree

Tags: trees

Consider a full binary tree of *n* nodes numbered from `1` to `n` in the common top-down left-to-right manner. For the sake of the question, we can consider the following tree:

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

I need to traverse from the root to some other node. Let's say I need to traverse to `6`.

Because I can see it from the picture, I know I have to go right to `3` and then left to `6`. But I need to be able to find that out mathematically without a picture.

When I am in the root, how do I know that `6` is in the right sub-tree and not in the left one? And then when I am in `3`, how do I know that `6` is in the left sub-tree and not in the left one?

Comment: Hint: express each number in binary.

Comment: @vadim123: I have tried that and it hasn't provided any results. Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: Can you see that the child of a node $i$ simply $2i$ (left) and $2i+1$ (right)?

Comment: @zed111: Yes, I can see that, however I don't know how that helps in figuring out where to go from `1` if I want to reach `6`.

Comment: The entries in a level are $2^i$ to $2^{i+1}-1$. You can figure out where to go from the root at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:
Let $a$ be the number where you currently are and $b$ the number you want to reach.
If $a$ has $n$ bits (in binary), then look at the $(n+1)^{th}$ bit of $b$, starting from left (upper bits). If it is $0$, go left, if it is $1$ go right.

Example $a = 3$ and $b = 6$. $a$ has $2$ bits in binary. Then the $3^{rd}$ bit of $b$ is $0$ starting from the upper bits: go left.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems to work. However, I was hoping for a more straightforward solution in the decimal system. Do you think there is none? If none gets presented in some time, I will accept your answer as it seems the best to me so far.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that any other solution will boil down to the same thing. To compute _mathematically_ the number of bits of a number $a$, you can use the formula $n = \lfloor log_2(a) \rfloor+1$ and the $k^{th}$ bit of a number is given by $\lfloor\frac{a}{2^{n-k}}\rfloor\ modulo\ 2$. In C language you would of course use bitwise operations instead (>> and <<).

Answer (score 2):

$6=110_2$. Go right, left.  (After the initial $1$ (at the root), for subsequent bits, go left for a $0$, right for a $1$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems to work. However, I was hoping for a more straightforward solution in the decimal system. Do you think there is none?

Comment: The children of node labelled $n$ are $2n$ (left child) and $2n+1$ (right child)--this can be shown inductively.  Going from $n$ to $2n$ corresponds to (right)-appending a $0$ to the binary representation of $n$; and going from $n$ to $2n+1$ corresponds to (right)-appending a $1$ to the binary representation of $n$.  I think this is probably simplest (compared to trying to do something with the decimal representation of $n$).

Answer (score 0):

You need a sorted binary tree, so, with those numbers, approximate and pick the mean number, say 3. This will result in a more balanced tree:

```
    3
   / \
```

Recursively do the same for those numbers $\leq 3$ on the left branch and those $\gt 3$ on the right branch.  So:

```
     3
    / \
   2   6
  /   / \
 1   4   7
      \
       5
```

Now when you insert() into the data structure, you add one number at a time and you can find its place by comparing to each node value and moving left or right depending on the result ($\leq, \lt$).  If you add in something already in the tree, just keep the value already in the tree.  That's the basic algorithm any way.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, however, I think you're assuming too much. I don't want to change the structure of the tree in any way. The tree from my question may not be sorted, but it is structured and named in such a regular fashion that there just has to be a simple mathematical solution. Are you saying there is none?